# Label click event after pressing enter on textbox c#

Tags: c#

I have a winforms sign in in c# that I would like to have it try login after pressing the enter key on the password box.

I have a username textbox, password textbox, and a label for my submit.

I have this for my enter keypress.

```
    private void password_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == (char)13)
        {

            signinbutton.Click();    //I was thinking something like this would work                        
        }
    }
```

Any ideas would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: @mellamokb I think the question is "How do I perform a click on a button in my form?", basicially.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume your code currently looks like this:

```
private void password_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)13)
    {
         // what do i do here?         
    }
}
private void signinbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    //do stuff
    //do stuff
    //do stuff
}
```

Here is what I recommend you do:

```
private void password_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)13)
    {
         DoStuff();
    }
}
private void signinbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    DoStuff();
}
private void DoStuff() {
    //do stuff
    //do stuff
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: went with this approach after I realized my DoStuff() wasn't that much stuff.  Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

An easier solution to this problem is just set the AcceptButton on your form to be your signinbutton, this will cause enter to hit the button by default, as long as focus is anywhere on the form.

Comment: This is good, provided this is the only button in the form, and the OP wants the button pressed from anywhere in the form, not just that one text box.

Comment: In which case you can set using the textbox.onfocus {acceptbutton=myButton;}

Comment: It doesn't need to be the only button on the form, just the one that he wants pressed, but yes it assumes he is ok with the enter key being pressed when focus is anywhere on the form not just in the password box as the post suggests (but I assume this is rarely the case)

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
signinbutton.PerformClick();
```

See [Button.PerformClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.performclick.aspx) for details.

If the password TextBox is the only text box on your form, you may also want to consider marking the `signinbutton` button as the default button.  This will cause this behavior to happen automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I made a button that wasn't visible and set it so that when someone hit the enter key, it would trigger the button.

```
  private void Textbox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        //if the enter key is pressed it triggers the submit button.
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            buttonSubmit_Click((object)sender, (EventArgs)e);

        }
    }

    private void buttonSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //this is what the enter key triggers. 
        MessageBox.Show("you hit the enter key");
    }
```